# How to access a spring controller object from a thymeleaf template?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to access a spring controller object from a thymeleaf template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in your controller you can add an object to `Model Attributes` like this

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    return "index";
}
```

And then in your `index.html` you can refer to the object as `${person}`. An example can be seen below.

```
<p th:text="${person}}"></p>
```

EDITED: 
Moreover, you can handle nullable variables with the `?` symbol:

```
<p th:text="${person.country?.popularity?}}"></p>
```

This example means the country of this person can be null such as the popularity of the given country.

If you have more questions with Thymeleaf, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend @Prebiutsta 's answer.
When you use your model object in your templete (like `index.html`), you can get the attributes of your object like this:

```
<label>Person Id: </label> <p th:text="${person.id}}"></p>
<label>Person Name: </label> <p th:text="${person.name}}"></p>
<label>Person Adress: </label> <p th:text="${person.adress}}"></p>
```

But it only works if your `Person.java` class has getters for all attributes that in use.

EDITED: 
Moreover, you can handle nullable variables with the `?` symbol:

```
<p th:text="${person.country?.popularity?}}"></p>
```

This example means the country of this person can be null such as the popularity of the given country.

If you have more questions with Thymeleaf, feel free to contact me.